# How to find a first even number in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

If there is a even number in the list, return the first one, and if there is no even number, return -1.
For example like this:

```
>>> first_even([5, 8, 3, 2])
8
>>> first_even([7, 1])
-1
```

I have tried some functions that are able to return the first even but no idea the -1. Pls anybody can give me an advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next()` for this -

```
def first_even(lst):
    return next((e for e in lst if e%2==0),-1)
```

Example runs -

```
>>> def first_even(lst):
...     return next((e for e in lst if e%2==0),-1)
...
>>> first_even([5, 8, 3, 2])
8
>>> first_even([7, 1])
-1
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found the problem after I asked the questions:(

Comment: One serious problem with this function is it will treat 0 as even! Try first_even([int(i) for i in list('038208493759824037493251836')])

Comment: @SIslam What makes you think `0` is not even? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113709/is-zero-an-even-number ?

Comment: Thanks it cleared my vista, negative numbers can also be even! Thanks really -http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Answer (score 0):

You may use `for` `else`

```
>>> def first_even(x):
    for i in x:
        if i%2 == 0:
            return i
    else:
        return -1
>>> first_even([5, 8, 3, 2])
8
>>> first_even([7, 1])
-1
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I forgot to use else to take the odd condition.

Comment: same here it will consider 0 as even!

Comment: change if to `if i > 0 and i%2 == 0:`